# "source: command not found" running script with git sh via cmder

Tags: bash, shell, cmder

I'm using cmder on windows https://github.com/bliker/cmder

I created my custom cmder task with the following commands

```
-new_console:d:C:\project > "C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login -i  -cur_console:d:C:\project
```

I need to add another command when this tab opens

```
source script.sh
```

But when I add it above in the commands I get

`'source' is not recognized as an internal or external command`

Comment: `source` is a bash command, not a sh command. Use `. foo`, not `source foo`, when using `sh` rather than `bash`.

Comment: Are you running bash? `source` is a bash-command (the POSIX way is `.`); cmder looks like it's only a terminal emulator? And not a shell?

Comment: After cmder command line opens if I run source script.sh from the command line it all works fine but if I try to run this from the COMMANDS list on terminal initizaliation it doesn't recognize source command

Comment: That error message "... is not recognized as an internal or external command" comes from the Windows command interpreter (similar to MS-DOS).

Answer (score 3):

You can use `-c` to pass a command to `sh` to have it run that but I don't believe you can do that **and** get an interactive session.

Which means if you need a command to be run at the start of an interactive session you want to use the `--init-file` or `--rcfile` to specify your startup file (instead of the default file). Though those might both be bash specific. I'm not sure.

If they are then you could try setting the `ENV` variable to the (absolute or variable/etc. expansion-able) path to your script before running the shell.